# sed using cached version of commands file, not seeing edits to file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script using sed -f sedcommands.txt, which works as expected.  If I put sedcommands.txt in the parent directory, and use sed -f ../sedcommands.txt, it keeps using the same version of the file even if I edit it.  It is using the version from the first time I put it into the parent directory.  Edits to the file don't change the output of sed.  I searched my computer and confirmed that I only have 1 file named sedcommands.txt on my only drive, so I'm not sure where it's getting an old version of the file.  I restarted my computer and it was still using an old version.  OSX Ventura 13.2.1 with HomeBrew coreutils installed.  Script is:

sed -f sedcommands.txt $1.txt > temp.txt
(works correctly)

or

sed -f ../sedcommands.txt $1.txt > temp.txt
(uses old or cached version of sedcommands.txt)

I tried rebooting but sed was still using an old version of the file.  Moved the sedcommands.txt file back into the current directory and took ../ out of the script, and it works properly (output of sed changes after I edit and save the file and run the script again).  But I would rather not have a separate copy of sedcommands.txt file in every subdirectory or keep moving it around.

Comment: If you stand in the directory from where you'd like to execute the script and do `cat ../sedcommands.txt`, does it show the correct version or an old version?

Comment: I find this very difficult to believe.

Comment: Remember that pathnames are relative to the user's working directory, *not* the directory containing the script. So you should use an absolute path for `sedcommands.txt`.

Comment: I am no longer able to replicate this.  I have no idea what was going on.  Maybe some weird filesystem glitch?  I ran a disk check and didn't find anything.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Symlinks may play some tricks on you depending on from where you access them.

Comment: One possible scenario. With directory `a/b/c` you first created `sedscript.sh` and `sedcommands.txt` in directory `a/b`. Copied `sedcommands.txt` to `a` and added `../` in script. Changedir to `a/b/c`. Run `../sedscript.sh` that will run the script in `a/b` and use the `sedcommands.txt` in `a/b`, not the later edited file in `a`.